# Viewing raw emails sent to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I have my workflow setup to receive email through SES and store it in an S3 Bucket. What are some workflows people have setup to download and view these raw emails?

Comment: did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: Nothing yet. :(